# Potentially dangerous request while passing escaped amp character

Tags: asp.net, escaping, ampersand

While making request to url `/Download/9483c374-c6f5-4b32-974b-2ad67fb2d3c2/true/test%26amp.pdf` I take **Potentially dangerous request ... (&)**.
Why? Amp is escaped. `ValidateRequest="false"` doesn't help too.